# Kubespray: How to add multiple GlusterFS disk volume devices for one node

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs, kubespray

I am playing with Kubespray and want to add GlusterFS persistent volumes. My inventory.ini looks like this:

```
[all] 
k8s-master    ansible_host=x.x.x.x
k8s-node-1    ansible_host=y.y.y.y disk_volume_device_1=/media/125GB_HDD.img

[kube-master] 
k8s-master

[etcd] 
k8s-master

[kube-node] 
k8s-master 
k8s-node-1

[k8s-cluster:children] 
kube-node 
kube-master

[gfs-cluster] 
k8s-node-1

[network-storage:children] 
gfs-cluster
```

But I would like to add more devices than just `disk_volume_device_1`. I tried `disk_volume_device_2=/media/20GB_HDD.img` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Kubespray](https://kubespray.io/#/) is for deploying a cluster.

If you want to change the capacity of deployed [`Persistent Volumes`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes), you can edit (`kubectl edit pv <name_of_pv>`) the `PersistenVolume.spec` and change the `capacity.storage` value.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: glusterfs 
spec:
  capacity:
      storage: "150Gi"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: glusterfs
    path: gluster
    readOnly: false
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

I recommend reading [Resizing Persistent Volumes using Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/).

Also you can read these docs [Deploying a Kubespray Kubernetes Cluster with GlusterFS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/master/contrib/network-storage/glusterfs).

If you would be interested in using [`Heketi`](https://github.com/heketi/heketi), please check this guide [Increase GlusterFS volume size in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/wescale/increase-glusterfs-volume-size-in-kubernetes-752e087bf065).

Comment: There is contrib to deploy glusterFs using Kubespray too: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/master/contrib/network-storage/glusterfs